# Why need to use super method in this code

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning classes and the inheritance but I faced the confusion of why to use the super method in child class. Here is the code:

```js
    class Animal {
        constructor(name, weight) {
            this.name = name;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    
        eat() {
            return `${this.name} is eating!`;
        }
    
        sleep() {
            return `${this.name} is going to sleep!`;
        }
    
        wakeUp() {
            return `${this.name} is waking up!`;
        }
    
    }
    
    class Gorilla extends Animal {
        constructor(name, weight) {
            super(name, weight);
        }
    
        climbTrees() {
            return `${this.name} is climbing trees!`;
        }
    
        poundChest() {
            return `${this.name} is pounding its chest!`;
        }
    
        showVigour() {
            return `${super.eat()} ${this.poundChest()}`;
        }
    
        dailyRoutine() {
            return `${super.wakeUp()} ${this.poundChest()} ${super.eat()} ${super.sleep()}`;
        }
    
    }
    
    console.log((new Gorilla("Jonas", 12)).dailyRoutine());
```

As you can see the gorilla class uses super method and if I remove that super method I get an error but WHY? I just cannot when to use super method and why?

Comment: Because you are extending `Gorilla` with `Animal`... So you have to instantiate `Animal` from within `Gorilla` (aka the call to `super`) so that you can access the methods from `Animal` but inside of `Gorilla`... For example, the `eat` method (lives in `Animal` but is being used in `Gorilla`)

Comment: Which of the `super`s did you remove and why? What do you think `super` does, and why did you think you could remove it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: @JonasWilms, hi Jonas, thank you for your kind comments, the reason I removed super() from inside constructor of its child is that I thought super() is not needed there, I mean, it is logical if we try to access method of parent class with super like super.sleep() but you can kill me))) I have no idea WHY we need to use super() inside constructor of the child class. I really hope for your simple explanation)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super()` inside the constructor allows you to pass arguments to the parent constructor.

```
class Parent {
  constructor(weNeedThis) {
    console.log(weNeedThis);
  }
}

const parent = new Parent("When constructing, it's easy to pass the argument");

class Child {
  constructor() {
    // But how do we pass an argument to the parent's constructor here?
  }
}
```

So in other words, we need `super()` sometimes to pass arguments to the parent constructor.

> if I remove that super method I get an error but WHY?

That's for consistency. If some constructors would call `super()` and others wouldn't, it is unclear when and how the parents constructor runs. Therefore it is specified, that *if you provide your own `constructor`, you have to call `super` before you can access `this`*. When `super()` gets called, the parent constructor gets run with the arguments provided, `this` gets initialized and is accessible from then on.

Comment: ok Jonas, can I imagine it like this we need to use super in constructor of child class because when we need to use method of parent class like eat() inside child class. As you can see "this.name inside eat()" and if we omit super in the constructor of child class, then this.name will not have value which is weird. Again, the reason to use super in constructor of a child is to ensure that when we decide to use, say, eat method inside gorilla then name has to be passed so that this.name has value. Is that right? I hope you got my point)))

Comment: it would also be weird if Gorillas wouldn't have a name although they are Animals.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `super()` initializes the `super`, or parent, class. The parent class and it's members must be initialized first, as the child class usually depends on them to some extent. You cannot inherit a class and not initialize the parent because you may not be able to access members that the child class depends on.

Comment: You might also explain `super.eat()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`super` gives you access to the parent class. In your specific example, you need to call the `Animal` constructor and provide the parameters that needs. The reason that it throws the error without it is that the `Animal` portion of your object can't be initialized without running through the constructor.

`super` will also give you reference to the other functions and properties within the parent class.

Check out the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) to get more information.